# Error: Could not resolve 'storysolo' from state 'index'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I have my index.php page with a ui-sref link as follows

```
 <a ui-sref="storysolo({ storyId: headline.nid })">
```

I have my main js file loading the angular code as follows

```
var rebelFleet = angular.module("CougsApp", ["ui.router","ngAnimate", "ui.bootstrap", "ngSanitize", "slick","CougsApp.headlines","CougsApp.story","CougsApp.recentstories" ]); 

rebelFleet.config(function($stateProvider) {



// For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: "",
      views: {
        "navViewPort": { templateUrl: '/components/nav/nav.html'
                       },
            "contentViewPort": {
                            templateUrl: '/components/headlines/headlines.html',
                            controller: "headlinesCtrl"
                        },
        "eventsViewPort": { templateUrl: '/components/scroller/scroller.html' },
        "bottomContentViewPort": { templateUrl: '/components/recentstories/recentstories.html',
                                 controller: "recentstoriesCtrl"
                                 },
        "rightsideViewPort": { templateUrl: '/components/social/social.html' },
        "footerViewPort": { templateUrl: '/components/footer/footer.html' }
      }
    })
```

Then I have my story.js file trying to load with it's own routing. as follows

```
    var ywing = angular.module('CougsApp.story', ["ui.router"]);

 ywing.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('storySolo', {
        url: '/story/:storyId',
            views: {
        "navViewPort": { templateUrl: '/components/nav/nav.html'
                       },
            "contentViewPort": { 
                            templateUrl: '/components/story/story.html',
                            controller: "storyCtrl"
                        },
        "footerViewPort": { templateUrl: '/components/footer/footer.html' }
      }
    })

 });
```

So when I load my page and click on the  ui-sref link I get this error

> Could not resolve 'storysolo' from state 'index'

my order of files being loaded is as follows

- angular.js,
- angular-sanitize.js,
- angular-ui-router.js,
- rebelFleet.js, (the main js file)
- story.js

I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the way the routes are being loaded and UI-Router hates it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you define your route as `storySolo` and then call it in the HTML as `storysolo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e37bCXxh8aSkD24yQ7ft?p=preview)

Believe or not, it is very simple - it is about case sensitivity. State names must fit on the 1) definition as well on the 2) call side

```
// small solo   
<a ui-sref="storysolo({ storyId: headline.nid })">  

// capitalized Solo
$stateProvider.state('storySolo', {...
```

so just use one or the other, e.g.:

```
// not small solo   
<a ui-sref="storySolo({ storyId: headline.nid })">  

// the same name here
$stateProvider.state('storySolo', {...
```

Check the [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/e37bCXxh8aSkD24yQ7ft?p=preview)

Comment: I didn't want to check this as the answer because it's admitting I'm an idiot. Thank you for your help though. I'm sure it would have taken another day to solve on my own.

Comment: You have solution and that's what counts! Enjoy UI-Router :)